# extract features from low resolution

Tags: deep-learning, feature-extraction, vgg16

I have medical images and need to extract features from the layer before the classification layer using `VGG` for example but the `resolution` of the images is not efficient... Are the features without improving this resolution will not be affected or do I need to improve the resolution before extracting the features?

[image]

I was doing processing in color images for extracting the features using VGG by this processing

```
preprocess = T.Compose([
    T.Resize(256, interpolation=3),
    T.CenterCrop(224),
    T.ToTensor(),
    T.Normalize((0.485, 0.456, 0.406), (0.229, 0.224, 0.225)),
])
image= load_img("aa.jpg", target_size=(224, 224,3))
proc=preprocess(image)
```

what if the images I have are `grayscale` or `blur` will this processing be suitable for them or do I need to change?

Comment: Question: what do you mean by "resolution of the images is not efficient"? Don't quite get it.

Comment: i attached one of them

Comment: What I mean is 1) what is not "efficient"? and 2) what does is it have to do with `VGG`?

Comment: i mean not clear enough by not efficient. that is my question in real .. is there a relation between the resolution of the images if i need to extract it using vgg model or not

Comment: I see. I don't think we usually use the word "efficient" to describe a blur image, but anyway let's go back to your question.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, the question is "would blur images affect the features extracted from `VGG`?"

Yes and no, depends on your application (i.e. "what do I want to use these features for?"). In general we don't know till we try. Rule of thumb is that if a human doctor can do it, there is at least a chance to work.

But technically, there shouldn't be anything stopping you from training/fine-tuning an `VGG` architecture and extract the features from it. Note that you  will need to adapt to the input size (e.g. 224x224x3 for `VGG16`) either by transforming your images or replacing the input layer of model.

**Edit** (to OP's additional comment)

Looks fine to me (though I admit not knowing what the `interpolation` does). It is a common practice to populate the 3 color channels with grayscale. There may be more advance techniques but I cannot recall (quite a while since I last work on medical image).

Comment: excuse me can you see the edit post , please

Comment: thanks a lot so excuse me if the images ate grayscale in the basic not RGB so is there any change that i can do it with this snippet code

Comment: Simplest way is to copy the same grayscale for all 3 channels.

Comment: For more advance methods, you can do some literature review.